# How to wait for a function to complete in a while() command?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a couple functions using jQuery and I want to use `await`, but it doesn't work. The `await function()` is inside a `while ()`. If that's the problem, how can I fix it? It is just two functions and the first is an async function.

I've tried to remove the `while()` and instead test the same thing at the end of the function and if `true` it would call itself again until false, but it runs incredebly fast(100's of times a second or faster) and that would cause problems. I've tried using promises, but I don't understand them so you can guess where that goes. I think I need a promise though, but I can't implement it.

The functions are as follows:

```
async function function1() {
  q=0;
  while (q<7) {
    // calls another function to get values
    await function2();
    q++;
  }
}
function function2() {
  //jQuery here
  $('.element').animate({
    top: '100px',
    left: '45vw'
  });
  return;
}
```

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p class='element' style='border: 2px solid black; width: 10vw; height: 10vw'></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there anything I can do?

This is a small script, it isn't my code exactly, just what is needed to remake the problem. It will run an animation over 7 different elements(incremented by q). I need it to wait because of not it will move them all at the same time, and I would prefer them to be moved one at a time. I've looked into promises, jQuery queues, and more. If it isn't possible, it won't hurt anything. I just want it to look nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to let function2 return a promise.

You can achive that by doing:

```js
function function2()
{
   return $('.element').animate({...}).promise();
}
```

Comment: How would I implement that? As I've said in the question, I don't know how to use promises yet, and every tutorial is confusing. Can you edit your answer to include how this would be achieved?

Comment: Is there a way to call the function instead? When I try that it stops after the first execution for some reason. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean it should repeatedly do something? I think, you would have to reset the position before starting the animation over, since the animate call only tells it where to go - not where to start. So after the first time it actually starts at the target position.

Comment: this is a small script, it isnt my code exactly, just what is needed to remake the problem. I should have included that, sorry. But yes, it will run an animation over 7 different elements(incremented by q). I need it to wait because of not it will move them all at the same time, and I would prefer them to be moved one at a time. I've looked into promises, jQuery queues, and more. If it isn't possible, it won't hurt anything. I just want it to look nicer. I will add this information to the question to prevent further misunderstandings. Thanks!

Comment: It would help, If you could provide a functioning example. The problem you still have is hard to guess.

For example, all calls to animate will move the same element right now.

Comment: Here is a link to the code: https://liveweave.com/aX3mx1

Comment: In that example: Function 1 is not async; There is no await before the call to function 2; return and .promise() are missing inside Function 2. If I changed that, it works consecutively.

Comment: See https://liveweave.com/cQK5Ns

Comment: omg, why didn't I think of that before? I should have thought to use return on that! Tysm!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add setTimeout or set where you want to

Comment: I have tried that actually. I forgot to add it in my question.  It doesn't work though. Any other ideas?